# Convert base64 string to PNG image in android

Tags: android, image, base64

I want to convert a **Base64** String to png for a `ImageView`.
I'm now using :

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

it works perfectly but i want a png image.
Thanks.

Comment: PNG is a **file format** (bitmap compression method to be more accurate). It has nothing to do with ImageView. In Android images are stored as Bitmaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use this**

```
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    // Bitmap Image
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

    String filename = "MyImage.png";
    File file= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dest = new File(file, filename);

    try {
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
         out.flush();
         out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Required Permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I have more than 1400 images, that will not be able to affect the performances?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
       ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        //encode image to base64 string
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.png, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        //decode base64 string to image
        imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
if (base64ImageData != null) {
   fos = context.openFileOutput("imageName.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(base64ImageData, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
   fos.write(decodedString);                        
   fos.flush();
   fos.close();             
}

} catch (Exception e) {

} finally {
if (fos != null) {
    fos = null;
}
}
```